# R: Know the total amount of positive values in a column using R

Tags: r

I have a column of different numbers and I would like to find out how many negative (or positive) values are in the column.

Comment: Probably the functions `table` and `sign` would be useful.

Comment: sum(mydf$col > 0)

Comment: length(x[x<0]) or for the number of unique values that are negative length(unique(x[x<0]))

Answer (score 0):

`sum(df$col > 0)` will give you the number of positive, `sum(df$col < 0)` gives the number of negatives.